# passing message with postMessage() not working

Tags: javascript, facebook, postmessage

Can anyone find out why this script is not showing the message, I am trying to post a message from facebook.com to my localhost file. But it does not work, for it. While its working for simple local file, when you change the window.open url to something.html.

**Code**

```js
     <script type="text/javascript">

     
       var win = window.open ("https://www.facebook.com/","mywindow", "width=350,height=250");
   win.opener.postMessage("Hello Nadee", 'http://localhost.com');

  // Create IE + others compatible event handler
  var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
  var eventer = window[eventMethod];
  var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

  // Listen to message from child window
  eventer(messageEvent,function(e) {
    console.log('origin: ', e.origin)
   
    // Check if origin is proper
    if( e.origin !== 'http://localhost.com' ){ return }

    console.log('parent received message!: ', e.data + e.origin);
  }, false);
```

Comment: Didn't you just wrote `if( e.origin != 'http://localhost.com/' ){ return }`..? Also, `"width=200,height=200"` is a bit odd name for a window ...

Comment: yes, and it is working

Comment: What I want to do is, to get the URL of the child window and send that as a message to the local file, how it could be done please help

Comment: Do you even have access to `win.opener.postMessage` here? I would have expected the Same Origin Policy to prevent that ...

Comment: postMessage is overcome the same origin policy !

Comment: Code Updated ! you can check it now

Comment: Nope, postMessage doesn't override Same Origin Policy, it only allows cross-scripting between domains you control yourself.

Comment: So how would I get that what I need